# How to apply Framework in any project?

Tags: java, architecture, frameworks, project

We do have various frameworks in java, like spring, jsf etc.

At the beginning of any project, how this frameworks are applied to project. If I want to use JSF in my project, what should be starting?

Is is based on architecture like MVC ? or in case of Spring, how to apply DI & AOP within project ?

How to mixup two frameworks in same project like JSF + Spring ?

How to decide architecture of any project ? What should be the first stage in development after deciding an architecture of the that project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home). It gives answers to most of your questions:

"AppFuse is an open source project and application that uses open source tools built on the Java platform to help you develop Web applications quickly and efficiently. It was originally developed to eliminate the ramp-up time found when building new web applications for customers. At its core, AppFuse is a project skeleton, similar to the one that's created by your IDE when you click through a wizard to create a new web project."